# Getting code to output on one line of the console

Tags: c#, format, repeat

I'm having a problem with the formatting output. Here's my code:

```
int[] Number = new int[15];
// int followup;

int Counter;

Random random = new Random();
for (Counter = 0; Counter < Number.Length; Counter++)
{
    int Rep = 0;
    Rep = random.Next(0, 345);
    Number[Counter] = Rep;
    Console.WriteLine("num:{0}", Rep);
}
```

It's putting out my numbers like

```
7
4
2
(repeat 15)
```

but I would prefer it to output like this:

```
6 2 7 4 (11 more)
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Well you are printing them as you generate them.  If you want them in order (???) wait until the end of the loop and sort them

Comment: Are you looking to print out the random numbers order?

Comment: Sorry I guess I was a little vague, I just want the numbers to be put into a row in the output, the order does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the Console.WriteLine to `Console.Write("{0} ", Rep);`

```
    int[] Number = new int[15];
    // int followup;

    int Counter;

    Random random = new Random();
    Console.Write("Num: ");
    for (Counter = 0; Counter < Number.Length; Counter++)
    {
        int Rep = 0;
        Rep = random.Next(0, 345);
        Number[Counter] = Rep;
        Console.Write("{0}" + (Counter < Number.Length - 1 ? ", " : ""), Rep);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: I had thought about that but then I ran into a problem, its adds "num: (number) on each one like: num: 14 num:84 etc. is there a better way so that it just outputs num (number), (number) , (number)?

Comment: What are you using for your compiler? Are you using an IDE?

Comment: I'm using Visual studio 2013

Comment: I'll explain a bit better, I would like the output to look more like this: Num: 1 5 6 8 but its outputting like Num: 1 Num: 5 Num: 6 Num: 8

Comment: Ok, gotcha. Just print out the title before the loop. See my edit.

Comment: Thats what I needed! Okay I understand now, thank you so much!

Comment: #SO always here to help!

Answer (score 2):

Inside the loop, change [`Console.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) to [`Console.Write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.write(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    Random random = new Random();
    Console.Write("Num: ");
    for (Counter = 0; Counter < Number.Length; Counter++)
    {
        int Rep = random.Next(0, 345);
        Number[Counter] = Rep;
        Console.Write("{0} ", Rep);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
```

and then call `Console.WriteLine()` outside the loop to move to next line

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have it like

> is there a better way so that it just outputs num (number), (number) , (number)

then why don't you use it like this?

```
Console.Write("{0} ,", Rep);
```

Should work fine

Comment: Well the problem also with that is that I would like it to output like

Num: 1 5 6 8

but it outputs like Num: 1 Num: 5 Num: 6 Num: 8

Answer (score 1):

I would create a string from the array and output the result at the very end.

```
int[] Number = new int[15];    
int Counter;
Random random = new Random();
for (Counter=0; Counter<Number.Length; Counter++)
{
    int Rep = 0;
    Rep = random.Next(0, 345);
    Number[Counter] = Rep;
}
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", Number));
```

Now you can create a reusable function and have a separation of concerns, business logic in one place (incrementing numbers), output in another place.

This will help you avoid copy and paste programming (copy and paste programming is when you copy and paste code with no changes, or maybe small changes).

```
int[] GetNumbers()
{
    int[] Number = new int[15];    
    int Counter;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (Counter=0; Counter<Number.Length; Counter++)
    {
        int Rep = 0;
        Rep = random.Next(0, 345);
        Number[Counter] = Rep;
    }
    return Number;
}

void DisplayNumbers()
{
    int[] numbers = GetNumbers();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", numbers));
}
```